# When making surface plot 3D from scattered data matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have some scattered 3D data which I want to make a surface plot.

The scattered data looks like the following.

[image: Scattered data, looks like some cliff or headland]

This is something I got when I made a surface plot using the data(I used the function grid data. See the following code below.)

```
[xq, yq] = meshgrid(-95:2:190, 20:0.5:170);
vq = griddata(XYZ(:,1),XYZ(:,2),XYZ(:,3),xq,yq,'natural');
surf(xq, yq, vq); %XYZ is the 3 column array contains the scattered data
```

[image: Surface plot result.]

I am not satisfied with the result because I wanted the points with same height to be connected with a line. In other words, the result I expected was more like the picture below.

[image: What I expected:]

Especially, at the surface plot (2nd picture) I do not want the wriggling valleys between the peaks. I want the peaks to be smoothly connected at the surface plot too (just like 3rd plot)

So my question is, how can I make the surface plot like the 3rd picture? Thanks.

Comment: @HunterJiang Thanks for your reply. The picture at the bottom is actually drawn by using function plot3. If I am correct, plot3 only supports a line plot, not a surface plot.

Comment: Yeap, sorry I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @HunterJiang No problem. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: could you please provide the data?

Comment: Please provide a link to your input data `XYZ` or downsize your problem and input to produce a minimal example that we can reproduce.